# Setup Global Options of RMySQL to use with sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf, rmysql

I am having a lot of problems with the coding of columns using sqldf and Rpostgree (when I do querys in datasets that contain letters of the Spanish language it converts them into strange characters), for this reason I want to move to MYSQL, but I find its documentation too confusing To use it with sqldf, I need to know how I can enter the parameters of my database to use sqldf with my previously configured database.

Example for Postgree:

> options (sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user = "postgres",
>            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.password = "test",
>            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname = "postgres",
>            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host = "localhost",
>            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port = 5432)

Someone knows how I can check the options of a specific package, in this case RMySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is in ?sqldf .  (You will need to refer to the MySQL documentation and RMySQL R package for details.  This could vary depending on which version of MySQL you are using.)  From `?sqldf`:

> On MySQL the database must pre-exist. Create a c:\my.ini or
>   %MYSQL_HOME%\my.ini file on Windows or a /etc/my.cnf file on UNIX to
>   contain information about the database. This file may specify the
>   username, password and port. The password can be omitted if one has
>   not been set. If using a standard port setup then the port can be
>   omitted as well. The database is taken from the dbname argument of the
>   sqldf command or if not set from getOption("sqldf.dbname") or if that
>   option is not set it is assumed to be "test". Note that MySQL does not
>   use the user, password, host and codeport arguments of sqldf. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html for
>   additional locations that the configuration files can be placed as
>   well as other information.

Also you could try using SQLite instead (which is the default back end and requires no installation). This works for me on Windows using the default SQLite backend.

```
library(sqldf)

d <- data.frame(x = "el perro saltó sobre el zorro perezoso")
sqldf("select * from d")
##                                        x
## 1 el perro saltó sobre el zorro perezoso
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after at least 3 hours of tortuous reading in multiple articles I could find a way to configure the mysql database to be used by sqldf and without dying in the attempt, I must warn you that this is the only way to work, since if you create a connection using RMySQL and then use the connection as a parameter in sqldf you will get multiple connection errors.

1. Create a my.cnf file
2. Here is everything necessary for it to work, it must be rs-dbi because this is the default testing environment used by sqldf to perform the queries, in addition, you must first install a mysql database using the old method of authentication, if you use encryption it will generate errors because sqldf drivers do not support it.

the local-infile parameters must be added to allow local data loading to the mysql database, otherwise it will generate errors.

> [rs-dbi] user = root password = test port = 3310 default-character-set
>   = latin1 host = 127.0.0.1 database = test local-infile [mysql] local-infile [mysqld] local_infile = 1

3. Just sqldf (x = test_query, drv = "RMySQL")
4. enjoy. The coding of the selected databases must be taken into account as the default in rs-dbi to avoid coding errors when making queries.